# Minimizing reflow with Marionette

Tags: javascript, marionette

I have a web application using Marionette that frequently needs to render large trees of nested views. I would like to avoid having as much reflow as possible by ensuring that the child elements are rendered and placed in the parent containers before the parent containers are placed in the DOM. How do I render these child elements to achieve this?

I'm currently rendering all children views in the `onRender` function, and as far as I can tell, they show up at the same time as the parent, but I can't find any documentation that tells me this is what its intended use is. I've also considered the use of `onBeforeShow`, which I know for sure is called before the view is placed in the DOM, but it makes rerendering much more complicated, since I can't just call `render` then.

As requested, here's a bit of code to give a better idea of what my situation is:

```
var Layout = LayoutView.extend({
    //...

    initialize: function() {
        listenTo(this.model, "some event indicating that data changed", this.render);
    },

    onRender: function() {
        //Will this new view render at the appropriate time to minimize page reflows?
        this.someRegion.show(new view(new model()));
    }
});
```

If I opt to use `onBeforeShow` instead, then I can either pass a reference to the container region

```
var Layout = LayoutView.extend({
    //...

    initialize: function() {
        listenTo(this.model, "some event indicating that data changed", this.callback);
    },

    callback: function() {
        this.container.show(this, {forceShow: true});
    },

    onBeforeShow: function() {
        //Does not cause a page reflow, but this solution isn't pretty.
        this.someRegion.show(new View(new Model()));
    }
});

var LayoutContainer = LayoutView.extend({
    //...

    onRender: function() {
        var model = new LayoutModel();
        var layout = new Layout({
            model: model,
            container: this.containerRegion
        });
        this.containerRegion.show(layout);
    }
});
```

Or have a parent object listening and telling the view when to render

```
var Layout = LayoutView.extend({
    //...

    onBeforeShow: function() {
        //Does not cause a page reflow, but this solution isn't pretty.
        this.someRegion.show(new View(new Model()));
    }
});

var LayoutContainer = LayoutView.extend({
    //...

    onRender: function() {
        var model = new LayoutModel();
        this.layout = new Layout({ model: model });
        listenTo(model, "some event indicating that data changed", this.rerenderSubview);
        this.containerRegion.show(this.layout);
    },

    rerenderSubview: function() {
        this.containerRegion.show(this.layout, {forceShow: true});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

### Listen to your model at the level that you need to act

When a views `el` is already attached to the DOM, rendering will attach the View to the DOM immediately, so the top level view will immediately get attached to the DOM.  What this means is that if you have your callbacks in onRender, they will be attached sequentially and you will have reflow.

If you instead put your subview shows into onBeforeShow, you'll build up a tree of Views that will be shown once, assuming the top View has had `show` called on it.  So the question is where to call a top level `show`.  I see 2 options

### The simple option

The easiest thing to do is to have your top level LayoutView show it's children in `onRender`, then all subsequent child views show their children in `onBeforeShow`.  This will potentially lead to a few paints (the top level and then one for each of the regions it's showing), but not a huge cascade of them, and likely not a performance issue (certainly it sounds like you don't have a visible performance issue yet.)

### The slightly more complicated option

If you really want only one repaint on model change, then you should create a wrapping View as described in the question, but rather than having the child view reference it directly, make sure the wrapping View has a reference to the model, and have it reshow your Layout when the model changes.  Then all of your callbacks can be `onBeforeShow`, and changes will result in a single paint.  There will be no connections between Views, and everything will be shown consistently in the same callback.

```
var LayoutContainer = LayoutView.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model,'change',this.reshowLayout);
    },

    reshowLayout: function() {
        var layout = new Layout({
            model: this.model,
            container: this.containerRegion
        });
        this.containerRegion.show(layout);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## Marionette inserts into the DOM *last*

Marionette actually doesn't attach the children of a `Collection`/`CompositeView` to the DOM until *everything* is rendered (parents, and children under the parent nodes). See how this happens in action:

In the `Region.show()`:

```
show: function () {
  // ...
  if (_shouldShowView) {
    view.render();
    // ...
    this.attachHtml(view);
  }      
  // ...
}
```

`region.show()` will call `view.render()` which will call `CompositeView.render()`,

```
render: function() {
  //...
  this._renderRoot();
  this._renderChildren();
  //...
  return this;
}
```

and notice in that function that first `view_renderRoot()` and then `view._renderChildren()` are invoked. These functions *do not* attach the rendered views to the DOM. They simply populate the templates and load the HTML nodes in memory.

#### Finally in the DOM

Back on `Regions.show()`, `region.attachHtml()` is what actually inserts the views into the DOM:

```
attachHtml: function(view) {
  // empty the node and append new view
  this.el.innerHTML='';
  this.el.appendChild(view.el);
},
```

If you don't use the region manager, and `.render()` your view yourself, you'll still have to append the view to the DOM like `region.attachHtml()` does.

### All children are attached to the parent before DOM insertion

In a CompositeView the rendered children get appended to the parent view in either `CompositeView.attachBuffer()` (if its the first render of the collection, or on `collection.reset()` ) or `CompositeView._insertBefore`/`_insertAfter` (sortable/unsortable children).

All of these ultimately implement some form of `collectionView.$el.append(childView.el)`.

In your scenario, where you mention that the parent is not yet in the DOM, then these are all attaching to a `collectionView.$el` which only lives in memory.

### Forget events

The beauty of the way Marionette was architected to render and inject children views is that you can forget about *when* to render the children. As long as you have your nested seed set up correctly from the beginning, the process will be recursive, and until the last child is rendered the top view will not return. This means all your children will be attached to the tree *before* you attach the nodes to the DOM.

If you have specific question about how to seed your nested views, post what your relevant code and I can give you more pointers.

Comment: You've addressed `CollectionView` and `CompositeView`, but what about `LayoutView`? You're also assuming that the view already knows all of its children at the time of rendering. When do I _add_ the children (using `show()`) so that they're rendered in the desired order?

Comment: You'll have to show me your code. Specifically, why calling render on the children views `onBeforeShow` is complicated

Comment: The view listens for changes in its model and rerenders accordingly. I would like to keep this logic confined to the view in question. If the subviews are added in `onBeforeShow`, then the view would have to either keep a reference to the containing region to be able to call `show()`, or the logic that checks for changes to the model would have to be in the `LayoutView` which holds that view. I edited my question with a bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

## Override `LayoutView.render()`

Based on comments, and after the problem was clarified I propose this solution:

The `LayoutView.render()` does some housekeeping and then does nothing more than call `ItemView.render()`. I suggest you override `LayoutView.render()` in your parent `LayoutView` as follows

```
render: function() {
  this._ensureViewIsIntact();

  if (this._firstRender) {
    // if this is the first render, don't do anything to
    // reset the regions
    this._firstRender = false;
  } else {
    // If this is not the first render call, then we need to
    // re-initialize the `el` for each region
    this._reInitializeRegions();
  }

  var layout = Marionette.ItemView.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);

  // After the parent rendered render and attach the child
  this.someRegion.show(new view(new model()));

  return layout;

},
```

I haven't tested this (not attempted it in the past), but its crazy enough that it just might work.

Comment: So Marionette doesn't provide any native way of doing this?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Considering that the only way to attach subviews to a Layout is by using the `onBeforeShow` event, it looks to me that Marionette isn't too concerned about attaching a sub-view to its parent before the parent is insterted. I think the thinking is that deep hierarchies would likely use a `CompositionView` based approach, where child injections are optimized in-memory. Nonetheless, I will ask around.

Comment: The answer above is very much in the spirit, if not Marionette, at least of Backbone. Before we got so comfortable with Marionette (and believe me, *I* have), overriding our own render function was SOP. Its even in line with the Marionette which sets out to provide common use-case tools in as small a package as possible. That's why overriding is perfectly ok as long as you steer away from Marionette internal methods.